# Where can I store a large amount of "business" data/object in my JS project?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I work with AngularJs. I have a factory providing services about *buildings*.

I have a lot of *buildings* (around 50-60) with a lot properties and sub-properties related to them (around 15-20, more or less complex).
Business requirements force me to store all the data about buildings in JS format.

So I created an object like that:

```
var Buildings = {
        myFirstBuilding: {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Building 1',
            quantity: 0,
            costs: {
                myFirstCost: {
                    name : 'Cost 1',
                    value: 10,
                    isAvailable: 0
                },
                mySecondCost: {
                    name :  'Cost 2',
                    value: 20,
                    isAvailable: 0
                }
            },
            workersAvailable: 0,
            type: 'Type 1',
            /*
              other properties...
            */,
        mySecondBuilding: {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Building 2',
            quantity: 3,
            /*
              and so on...
            */
```

I can update the structure of this object if needed. The only requirements is to be able to store it in user's browser and to "JSON it" when it's needed.

Where should I store this object in my project? Can I reference it from an external file in my factory? Should I include it directly in my factory?

Do you see any inconsistencies in this object as it's actually made in my example above?

Comment: Well if it is in a JavaScript file it is in the "cache" and technically in the user's browser. Are they referring to local storage? Do you ask them what they mean by storing it in the browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got 3 options as far as I see it:

1. Use an angular value or constant do store the data, if you just need
   to render it, and don't require database search/filter capabilities,
   and it's small enough.
2. If it's large, but not huge, and you don't need database
   search/filter, store it in local storage and read it using an angular service.
3. If it's very large and/or you need db search/filter use
   [indexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) on the browser. As some implementations of indexedDB
   are pretty broken, you should use a wrapper library such as
   [ydn-db](https://github.com/yathit/ydn-db).